# Scala: How to use function as a parameter?

Tags: scala, function

I have a function:

```
sigma(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)(f: (Int, Int, Int, Int) => Double): Double
```

I need to set it as a parameter of another function:

```
bigPi(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)('Here should be sigma'):Double
```

How to define a type of sigma correctly and use it as an argument of bigPi?

Comment: Note: those two are *not* functions. They are methods. Functions and methods are fundamentally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def sigma(x:Int, y:Int, z:Int, a:Int)(f:(Int,Int,Int,Int) => Double):Double = 1.1

def bigPi(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)(
             f: (Int,Int,Int,Int) => ((Int,Int,Int,Int) => Double) => Double
         ):Double = 2.2

bigPi(1,2,3,4)(sigma)
```

The IntelliJ IDE says there are unnecessary parentheses but the compiler says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def bigPi(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, a: Int)(s: (Int, Int, Int, Int) => ((Int, Int, Int, Int) => Double) => Double) = whatever
```